# How to deploy an API in WSO2 ESB referring to 3 endpoint services in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Trying to deploy an API which can gather response from multiple services (endpoints) in DSS (Application Server) and combine the responses in ESB.

Consider API as "Person" it has a GET method "getperson" 
"getperson" -- accepts personID as the parameter (query filter).

RESPONSE:

```
<person>
    <id\>
    <name\>
    <type\>
    <address>
        <street\>
        <apt\>
        <city\>
        <state\>
        <zipcode\>
    </address>
    <image>
        <id\>
        <description\>
        <title\>
    </image>
<person>
```

services in DSS are as follows ::

1. person_service

RESPONSE:

```
<person>
    <id\>
    <name\>
    <type\>
    <addressid\>
    <imageid\>
</person>
```

2. address_service

RESPONSE:

```
 <address>
        <street\>
        <apt\>
        <city\>
        <state\>
        <zipcode\>
    </address>
```

3. image_service

RESPONSE:

```
 <image>
    <id>
    <description>
    <title>
</image>
```

I was able to create services successfully in DSS.  But unable deploy an API using all the 3 service endpoints into one API GET method call.

I was following the sample given in the documentation for service chaining http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Service+Chaining

But, in that sample it was done using proxy service.  I am not sure how to connect that to API's

ESB version: 4.6.0 
DSS version: 4.0.1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same service chaining logic in API. If you look at API configuration, where you can define mediation logic as InSequence and OutSequence like you do for proxy service.

At the same time, you can define a proxy service with same logic, and provide that proxy service as your endpoint for your API.

Comment: Thank you for the Response.  when i create a proxy service I need to specify the publishing WSDL.  I have selected the option "Specify inline".  do i need to create a separate WSDL.  Because i need to combine the responses from more than one service (I can't use the WSDL for one specific service).  How to generate the WSDL file in ESB.

Comment: Publish WSDl option is used to publish a wsdl for clients to understand the service definition. If you don't like to publish a wsdl for the proxy you don't need to. But, if you publish a wsdl, the incoming request for the proxy should follow the wsdl schema definitions

Comment: Thank you, I selected the Publishing WSDl as "None".  It is still showing the Endpoints as "http://null:8888/....".  I am not sure why it showing me null.

Comment: Even when i tried to open the WSDL file.  I am getting the error "OOps! Google Chrome could not find null:<port number>".  I created a new proxy service following :: ScreenCast - Service Chaining with WSO2 ESB "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmNf-2VljLQ".  still ending up with same error

Comment: I tested the services in DSS.  They are working fine.

Comment: This is not api chaining; though WSO2 continues to try to say you are chaining in the API the chaining is happening on the server and hence it is METHOD chaining. if this were a stateless and dynamic api call where the chain is defined and handled with one request and response and did not have to be predefined on the backend, then you could call it an API CHAIN. (see rules for API chaining spec - https://github.com/orubel/grails-api-toolkit-docs/wiki/API-Chaining )